# Datagrid row and column color in Wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am developing a wpf application. Now I would like to color specific column and row while clicking checkbox. Color will change depending on the properties I'll bind. Please inform me if you have any idea. My working template is as follows,

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking but I would suggest applying a style to the rows and columns and then using a DataTrigger to change the style that gets applied depending on the whether the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: I want that if I click on the checkbox nr. 7, background color of the row and the column nr. 7 will change. If you look at the image I attached, pink color is nr 7.